# Calling function of self hosted wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new to WCF and hosting a WCF service in a Console Application where i now want to call a function inside the service.

Program.cs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService));
    host.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Service started at {0}", DateTime.Now);
    Console.ReadLine();
    host.Close();
}
```

The TestService contains a function that i want to call now.

App.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="TestServer.TestService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="TestServer.ITestService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8090/TestService/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I found out that i have to user a ChannelFactory, but i have no idea how to implement it into my code so it works.

Comment: You want to call WCF functions that you've implemented?

Comment: You need to create a **client** for this service (using `svcutil` on the command line, or by using `Add Service Reference` inside Visual Studio) and call that method you want

Comment: Yes. I want to call a WCF function that i hosted in same project. I tryed adding a service reference before, but it wouldn't work in the same project as the service is hosted. I guess you mean that i want to call the function on the client but i don't i want to call it from the server (console application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finaly found a nice example on how to use the ChannelFactory so that everything works fine. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/channel-factory-in-wcf/